# use elements ID to find value in object JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm looping through some elements by class name, and adding event listeners to them. I then grab the id of the selected element (in this case "tom"), and want to use it to find the value of "role" in the "tom" object. I'm getting undefined? can anyone help?

```
var highlightArea = document.getElementsByClassName('highlightArea');


for (var i = 0; i < highlightArea.length; i++) {
  highlightArea[i].addEventListener("mouseover", showPopup);
  highlightArea[i].addEventListener("mouseover", hidePopup);
}

function showPopup(evt) {
  var tom = { title:'tom', role:'full stack man' };
  var id = this.id;
  var role = id.role;
  console.log(role)
}
```

Comment: What is this.id? You probably meant `var id = dom.title;`

Comment: this.id is the id of element i'm hovering over, in this case  ('tom'),

Answer (score 1):

1. You are not selecting the elements correctly, the class is `hightlightArea` and you are querying `highlightArea` (missing a 't'), so, no elements are found (you can easily discover that by debugging or using `console.log(highlightArea)` that is the variable that holds the elements found.
2. Just because the id of an element is the same name as a var, it doesn't mean that it have the properties or attributes of the variable... So when you get the Id, you need to check which one is and then get the variable that have the same name.
3. Also, you are adding the same listener two times `mouseover` that way, just the last would work, it means just `hidePopup`. I changed to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, this way will work correctly.
4. After that, you will be able to achieve your needs. Below is an working example.

```js
var highlightArea = document.getElementsByClassName('hightlightArea');
var  mypopup = document.getElementById("mypopup");
var tom =  { title:'tom', role:'marketing'};
var jim = { title:'jim', role:'another role'};

for (var i = 0; i < highlightArea.length; i++) {
    highlightArea[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", showPopup);
    highlightArea[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", hidePopup);
}

function showPopup(evt) {
  let ElemId = this.id;
  let role;
  let title;
  if (ElemId == 'tom'){
    role = tom.role;
    title = tom.title;
  }else if (ElemId == 'jim'){
    role = jim.role;
    title = jim.title;
  }
  
  let iconPos = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  mypopup.innerHTML = role;
  mypopup.style.left = (iconPos.right + 20) + "px";
  mypopup.style.top = (window.scrollY + iconPos.top - 60) + "px";
  mypopup.style.display = "block";  
}

function hidePopup(evt) {
  mypopup.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="hightlightArea" id="jim">Div Jim</div>
<div class="hightlightArea" id="tom">Div Tom</div>
<div  id="mypopup"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your function 'showPopup' you have this:

```
var id = this.id
```

but this.id is not defined. You probably meant to write this:

```
var title = dom.title;
```

Comment: this.id is the id of element i'm hovering over ('tom'), but if I then do id.role i get undefined?

Comment: Can you make a plnkr? Because your id is probably a number, not an array or an object. So id.role does not exist.